# How to accept a buddy request in XMPP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

How can I accept incoming buddy request in XMPP?

This code helps me to catch incoming request:

```
public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didReceivePresence presence: XMPPPresence) {
    print("did received presence : \(presence)")

    if presence.type() == "subscribe" {

    }
}
```

But after this I do not know how to accept this request. I searched a lot and found these answers written in ObjectiveC:

```
[self.xmppRoster acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:[presence from] andAddToRoster:YES];
```

Another:

```
XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"friendsemailid or username"];
[xmppRoster addUser:newBuddy withNickname:nil];
```

And this:

```
[xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:[tempPresence from]];
```

But noone helps me. In swift I cannot use that. There is not such methods. Any help? How can I accept or reject incoming buddy request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `XMPPFramework` by **robbiehanson**, then you can integrate it in your swift project and accept request like:

```
let jId = XMPPJID.jidWithString(contact)
xmppRoster!.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom(jId, andAddToRoster: true)
```